# Skylight Modal React component - clear data beforeOpen

Tags: reactjs

it currently causes an infinate loop and stalls my browser. Any ideas? I would like to clear the data before it opens, otherwise I get a flash of data from the previous modal call.

```
  clearNotes: function(){
        this.setState({notes: ''});

},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <SkyLight ref="notesDialog" title="View Notes" 
            beforeOpen={this.clearNotes} showOverlay={true} >
                <DataGrid data={this.state.notes}
                          onSort={this.handleNotesSorting}
                          currentSortKey={this.state.notesSortKey}
                          sortIsAscending={this.state.notesSortIsAascending}>
                    <Column header="User" key="user" />
                    <Column header="Notes" key="note" />
                    <Column header="Type" key="type" />
                    <Column header="Date" key="date" renderWith={DateFormat} />
                </DataGrid>
            </SkyLight>
```

Comment: Is the call to `setState` in `clearNotes` causing it? What debugging have you done? You'll need to provide more information and a reproduction as the demo page works.  http://marcio.github.io/react-skylight/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is that the `beforeOpen` event is fired every time, react rerenders itself. -> this will call the setState method -> this will rerender the component -> ...

You could try to add a `shouldComponentUpdate` method to check if the state realy has changed. This could look like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    nextState.notes === this.state.notes ? return false : return true;
}
```

NOTE: You should check all properties and state. `shouldComponentUpdate` will ALWAYS cancel the rerendering process if it returns false! Even when the state or the props has changed.